Ordering the bars in a bar chart with multiple grouping variables
Here is a MWE.
df <- data.frame(Y = c(1:12),
                 Combination = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6),
                 Treatment = c("AX", "AY", "AY", "AX", 
                               "BZ", "BY", "BZ", "BX", 
                               "BY", "BX", "BX", "BY"),
                 Stage = rep(c(1,2), 6)
                      )

For this data, I want to create a bar chart where the x-axis is grouped by Combination, the bars are filled by Treatment, and within each combination, I want the bars to be ordered by stage.
The following is my code which can only achieve the first two conditions. I searched for some solutions, but they didn't work well for this particular dataset.
my_greys <- c("#000000", "#707070", "#000000","#707070", "#CCCCCC")

ggplot(test.df, aes(y = Y, fill = factor(Treatment), x = Combination  ) ) +
   geom_bar(position='dodge', stat='summary', fun='mean', show.legend = T) +
   theme_classic() + 
   scale_fill_manual(values = my_greys)


My purpose: I want the bars (filled by Treatment) in each Combination are ordered by the Stage variable.

Use the group aesthethic, e.g. like so:
ggplot(test.df, aes(factor(Combination), Y, fill = factor(Treatment), group = Stage)) +
  geom_bar(position='dodge', stat='summary', fun='mean')



thanks a lot! May I ask an additional question: How can I add the label "Treatment" on top of the label "1 2 3 4 5 6" (indicating the combination)?

See the labels argument for scale_x_discrete(). You could e.g. pass a function like + scale_x_discrete(labels = \(x) paste("Treatment\n", x))

Hi, Axeman. Thanks a lot for your suggestion. The suggestion does not work, actually all the x-axis ticks become missing. I looked at the label argument of the scale_x_discrete() function, however, I still do not know how to do it. Would you please elaborate more? or should I ask an independent question since this is a new question.
